# What &= operator do?

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

i just starting to learn c# and cant really understands what this operator do. Can somebody explain in easy language? Below example of my code.

```
int z = 4;
z &= 599;
Console.WriteLine(z);
```

Answer (score 2):

Writing `z &= 599` is same as writing `z = z & 599`, which is a bitwise operator. If you want to learn about bitwise operators, [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_bitwise_operators.htm) have I found a great website for reference for C#.